# libreoffice cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: c++, crash, libraries, libreoffice

when I try to open the application on linux it crashes and prints this lines :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) soffice.bin: common.c:108: llvm_codegen: Assertion `error == 0' failed.
```

I don't know how to proceed.Does anyone know how to fix it?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do? Open LibreOffice? Have you tried to install c++ compiler first?

Comment: yes when I try to open LibreOffice it shows the Openning Logo then crashes.Yes I've already installed c++ compiler.

Comment: That would be a question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) I suppose, it's problem with Linux rather than C++

Comment: I'll try to post the problem there ,maybe someone could help.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: Can you explain?